# Converting from SVN to Git with submodules

Tags: svn, git, git-submodules

We currently use subversion as our version control system, we have decided that we are moving to git. I have been having a hard time moving my subversion system with a standard layout into git. I have used `git svn` as much as I can.

What i need to accomplish is convert our subversion system to git with all commit history and as well as tags and branches. Then to be able to separate each of the projects into separate git repositories with their individual history, then combine each of these individual repositories into submodules.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to most easily accomplish this.

```
svnroot/
|-- branches
|-- tags
|-- trunk
    |-- project A
    |-- project B
    `-- project C
```

Please and thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer for the svn structure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502847/converting-from-svn-to-git-with-submodules/4504410#4504410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your svn repository layout is:

```
svnroot/
|-- projectA
|   |-- branches
|   |-- tags
|   `-- trunk
|-- projectB
|   |-- branches
|   |-- tags
|   `-- trunk
`-- projectC
    |-- branches
    |-- tags
    `-- trunk
```

Then you could create separate git repositories for each project e.g., `projectA`:

```
$ git svn clone --stdlayout https://svn.example.net/svnroot/projectA
```

After that you could create the main git repo ([`git init`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html)) and add the created git repos for `project{A,B,C}` as submodules to it ([`git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)).

*But* it is probably not what you want; from the `git submodule` manual:

> Submodules allow foreign repositories
>   to be embedded within a dedicated
>   subdirectory of the source tree,
>   always pointed at a particular commit.
>
> They are not to be confused with remotes, which are meant mainly
>   for branches of the same project; submodules are meant for different
>   projects you would like to make part of your source tree, while the history of
>   the two projects still stays completely independent and you cannot
>   modify the contents of the submodule from within the main project.

If you'd like to modify `project{A,B,C}` from within the main project and keep the unite history of the projects then the submodules are not appropriate for the task.

---

For the provided svn repo layout:

```
svnroot/
|-- branches
|-- tags
|-- trunk
    |-- projectA
    |-- projectB
    `-- projectC
```

try to create the git repositories using `--trunk`, `--branches`, `--tags` arguments e.g.:

```
$ git svn clone                       \
>    --trunk trunk/projectA           \
>    --branches branches              \
>    --tags  tags                     \
>    https://svn.example.net/svnroot  \
>    projectA
```

On completion the `.git/config` file should contain something like:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = https://svn.example.net/svnroot
        fetch = projectA/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
        branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
        tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

You could use [`--ignore-paths=<regex>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) to skip matching paths from the project.